# Can't find zap.sh (v2.7.0) on macbook

Tags: owasp, zap

Just installed OWASP Zap 2.7.0. When I try to run command line, zap.sh is not found. It does not show up in Applications folder either.

command: 
/Applications/OWASP\ ZAP\ 2.app/Contents/Java/zap.sh -quickurl https://xxx.yyy.abc:1234/ -quickout ~/zapreport.xml -cmd

response:
-bash: /Applications/OWASP ZAP 2.app/Contents/Java/zap.sh: No such file or directory

Mac O/S 10.13.4
Used installer: MacOS Installer 2017-11-28  179 MB

Comment: Installing the cross platform version includes zap.sh, which allows running from the command line rather than the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

As per: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQrun#mac-os

> Generally, most user's tend to use the Mac OS build, which is a
>   ordinary Mac OS app that can be started as any other app: Double-Click
>   on the app to start it. If you have downloaded the Linux package,
>   which can also be run on Mac OS, you can use the 'zap.sh' script, as
>   per linux.

So you'll need to grab the Linux or Cross Platform package I guess: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads

Or you could refer to: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpCmdline which suggests:

> /Applications/OWASP\ ZAP.app/Contents/Java/zap.sh

Comment: Just like zap.sh starts zap is there a shutdown script as well? if so what is it

Comment: Don't think so, though it's a gui so just close it? Or, if you've launched in daemon mode call the shutdown API endpoint.